# Context Error with Pyglet (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opengl, pyglet

I am trying to run the following test code for Pyglet:

```
    import pyglet

pyglet.options['shadow_window'] = False

# Specify the OpenGL version explicitly to request 3.0 features, including
# GLSL 1.3.
# Enable depth buffer and double buffering as well
config = pyglet.gl.Config(double_buffer = True, 
                          depth_size = 24, 
                          major_version=3, 
                          minor_version=2, 
                          forward_compatible = True)

# Create a context matching the above configuration.  Will fail if
# OpenGL 3 is not supported by the driver.
window = pyglet.window.Window(config=config, visible=False)

# Print the version of the context created.
print('OpenGL version:', window.context.get_info().get_version())
print('OpenGL 3.2 support:', window.context.get_info().have_version(3, 2))

window.close()
```

However, I am receiving the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dwill\Downloads\test (1)\pyglet_ogl3.py", line 16, in <module>
    window = pyglet.window.Window(config=config, visible=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 131, in __init__
    super(Win32Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 559, in __init__
    self._create()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 261, in _create
    self.context.attach(self.canvas)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py", line 198, in attach
    'OpenGL 3 contexts.')
ContextException: Require WGL_ARB_create_context extension to create OpenGL 3 contexts.
```

My hardware is NVIDIA 650M with the latest driver. The test file in the pyglet directory did run successfully.

Comment: A Geforce 650M _should_ support GL 3.2 just fine, and nivida does of course support the `WGL_ARB_create_context` extension. Since this seems to be a mobile platform, I can only guess that you mabe are on a notebook with nvidia "optimus" technology where both an nvidia GPU and an intel IGP are present, and you end up using the wrong GPU.

Comment: I verified that I was using my Nvidia GPU, and I get the same error on my desktop, which has 2 970s. My OpenGL version is version 4.4, and after doing some research, it's apparently an issue with pyglet being unable to recognize my OpenGL version, but I cannot find a fix